# How to convert string of time to milliseconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string which contains time (Hour-Minute-Second-Millisecond):

```
"00:00:12.750000"
```

I tried to convert it to milliseconds number without any success:

```
dt_obj = datetime.strptime(" 00:00:12.750000",'%H:%M:%S')
millisec = dt_obj.timestamp() * 1000
```

I'm getting error:

```
ValueError: time data ' 00:00:12.750000' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'
```

How can I convert it to milliseconds ? (it need to be 12*1000+750 = 12750)

Comment: you should fix the typo `dt_obj = datetime.strptime(" 00:00:12.750000",'%H:%M:%S')` should be written as `dt_obj = datetime.strptime("00:00:12.750000",'%H:%M:%S')`. Then you would get another error, update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python `datetime.strptime()` method to parse the time string into a `datetime object`.

So for that your code looks like:

```
from datetime import datetime

time_str = "00:00:12.750000"
time_obj = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M:%S.%f').time()

milliseconds = (time_obj.hour * 3600000) + (time_obj.minute * 60000) + (time_obj.second * 1000) + (time_obj.microsecond / 1000)

print(milliseconds)
```

Output:

```
12750.0
```